# Compare Disparate Data

Tags: c#, sql

We currently have a process where we receive an inventory file from a vendor every hour.  We need to compare that inventory data in the file to what we currently have in our DB.  Any thoughts/ideas on how you would approach this?

Here is what we are doing currently:

We pull the data from the db table into C# and do the same with the file then use LINQ to compare.

We had originally been staging the file data into a separate db table then comparing.

There can be up to about 100,000 records in the file.

Thanks in advance.....

S

Comment: Seems to be a reasonable approach, especially if your code to compare the data is written in C#.  Are you seeing any problems that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx). As a data flow engine, it has all sort of optimizations around the whole process of reading, processing and writing data that your application will miss. See [Considerations for High Volume ETL Using SQL Server Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc671624.aspx) for an introductory discussion on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Can the vendor include a last updated datetime field in the inventory file?  It would be a lot simpler to only process changes than iterating through 100,000 records.

Comment: They do, but we have found lots of problems/inconsistencies with that field that have led to oversells.  Thanks for the info though Dave...that is what we had originally tried.